# Vuex - Module state returns undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

am a little confused as to why the state property would return `undefined`. am new to vue.js and really need to understand how this works.

**Here is what i've done**

in the state.js file for let say todo module, i have

```js
const state = () => {
    return {
        todos: [
            {
                id: 1,
                title: 'Go outside'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                title: 'Come back in'
            }
        ]
    }
}
export default {
    state
}
```

i have an index file where i join everything together and export it

```js
import state from './state'
import getters from './getters'
import actions from './actions'
import mutations from './mutations'

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

and in the store entry point i have

```js
import Todos from './modules/todos'
export default 
  modules: {
    Todos
  }
})
```

So, the problem is, actions works perfectly but the state is affecting other like getters and mutations since the state properties was undefined.

vue-devtool stop working in my browser so i tried to `console.log(this.$store.state.todos)` but yeah, it undefined

Comment: Could you try `this.$store.state.Todos` ??

Comment: that returned an object but i would like to have access to the todos property not just in the computed but also in getters and mutations

Comment: Could you try doing what @Mahamudul mentioned and make your export statement for state to be `export default state`

Comment: As for getters and mutations, you can assume you will be getting `state` as an argument since Vue will make it available for getters and mutations when you merge them together at the end as one module. please share your getters and mutations files for more info

Comment: i have done that, just can't figure out how to double-check all of them "getters" before using them in actual component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to modify the state.js file. you should export like below

```
export default {
    state: {
        todos: [
            {
                id: 1,
                title: 'Go outside'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                title: 'Come back in'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I think state is supposed to be a function and not an object. I agree with your initial comment that it should be `export default state` instead of `export default {state}`

Comment: state should not be a function. if you use function then it should return state object with the name of state. but this solution will be nice

Comment: how do i double-check `...mapGetters(['myTodos'])` before using it in my component

Comment: is your state value ok? and share your getters.js file

Comment: That's what am trying to figure out.

Comment: update your post with getters.js. or upload your project in codesandbox or codepen